# Video player that has a cross dissolve option when changing the clip

Tags: video

so I need a Video Player, that can change Videoclips, using cross dissolve or overlay. It will be used by a DJ and he would like to be able to switch the Videos live by himself but not having any hard cut.
Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The functionality you seek is standard for a item called a Video Switcher.  Video switchers can be found as both standalone units ([low-end](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/atemtelevisionstudio) to [4K broadcast](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/atem)) and as [software](https://livestream.com/studio/software) (also low-end to high-end).  In the latter case, the computer running the switcher needs video I/O functionality, which typically requires adding one or more special cards (video I/O is different than a graphics card driving a computer monitor).